# Trying to install countertop/bar on an existing halfwall

Tags: drywall, kitchens, kitchen-counters, countertops, kitchen-island

Being the poor person I am, I am trying to slowly upgrade my kitchen whenever able. My parents got new counter tops and saved their old formica counters for me. I currently have an L shaped half wall about 6-8in wide. The outer side of the "L" is flat and finished with drywall (the top is drywall as well), and the inner side of the "L" is curled around cabinets/counter and my stove which sit about 6-7" lower than the top of the half wall. Because the top of the half wall is drywall finished, it got pretty messed up and eaten through by sweating drinks and such over the years. I recently repaired it, and was able to confirm that the half wall has a metal frame.

I see countless videos on how to install a half wall bar, but every single one includes building the wall from scratch which is why I'm here. I've got the cuts for my formica all planned out and ready to go, I just need to figure out what I've got to do to make sure it is installed properly and has enough support that it doesn't eventually end up falling off. I don't have an exact measurement for how far over the wall I want the formica to hang, but I know it will be a maximum of 4in or less, and honestly if I need to trim it down so there's no overhang at all I am more than willing to- I just hate this "drywall counter top" situation I've currently got and need to change it. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Hi Jessica, sounds like an interesting project. Would you be able to post a sketch or drawing of what you have in mind for this half wall rework? Including a photo of the existing location and and the counter materials would be useful as well to being able to offer suggestions. The biggest challenge that I can see is how to finish the ends and edges of the used counter top material.

Comment: Here is the (not very good) drawings I did on my phone to explain to my husband what m  plan is, and pictures of the counter top pieces! I plan to use the island counter top for this project and save the rest for future projects! I have a few random old pictures where you can see parts of the half wall as well as a screenshot I just took from my furbo dog camera, and I will add better ones once I get home from work later!
https://photos.app.goo.gl/tkRY47hmG94DXZGr5

Comment: I just realized I should have added that my eventual plan is to use a counter paint and resin to re-finish my counter tops- this new addition included. It doesn't match my current counters so I was thinking of sanding down the edges of the piece I use, getting a good layer of clear coating on it, and then attempting to paint over that :)